# How can I recover vbaproject.bin from my corrupt powerpoint.pptm file

Tags: vba, data-recovery, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a .pptm file with 70 hours of code work in it. It has become corrupted and I have no backup (very stupid I know!). What I do have is the .ppam which was generated from a slightly earlier version of it. When I open the VBA editor, I can see all the modules of code, but when I try to open them nothing happens. There does appear to be information in the vbaproject.bin file. I am running Windows 10.

Does anyone know how I can recover this work (preferably the code in the .pptm file, if not is it possible to revert the .ppam file?)

I have tried exporting the modules, but when I do no file appears in the selected folder. I also downloaded two pieces of software that claim to be able to help (bit recover vba macro remover and vbp), but to no avail. My search is continuing, but any help here would certainly be greatly appreciated!!

UPDATE: I have managed to revert to a recent version of the code by copying the VBA files from the .ppam using the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569893/edit-a-ppam-file-for-customizing-an-add-in

However, there is still some recent work missing that I would like to recover from the corrupt file.

Comment: Have you tried renaming your .pptm file to .zip then opening it in 7-Zip?  I've used this technique in the past to locate and save VBA macros found therein.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @leeharvey1. Following your suggestion, I've just tried with 7-Zip and it allows me to dig deeper into the vbaProject.bin. I can see the modules in there. How can I access the code in them?

Comment: To view contents, see https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-project-bin-and-protection/. BTW, no need to rename a file to open in 7-Zip, particularly if you've added the context menu for 7-Zip: right-click *any* file, even executables, and "Open Archive".

Comment: Thanks @DrMoishePippik, for the tip. I've downloaded or tried to download the solutions on that page and I was not able to use them/the links don't work anymore